# How to parameterized setUp method with nose_parameterized

Tags: python, nose, parametrized-testing

I'm using nose_parametrized package in my project and @parametrized.expand decorator on class level. But I don't know how to use a parameter for my setUp class. Code looks like that:

```
from nose_parameterized import parameterized    

@parameterized.expand(['par1', 'par2'])
class MyTestClass(TestCase):

    def setUp(self, par):
        super(TestCase, self).setUp()

        if par == "par1":
            do_something()
        elif par == "par2":
            do_something_else()

        do_more(par)
```

Such approach cause `TypeError: setUp() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`

What is the correct approach?

Answer (score 0):

Use `parameterized_class`:

```
from parameterized import parameterized_class

@parameterized_class(('par', ), ['par1', 'par2'])
class MyTestClass(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        super(TestCase, self).setUp()

        if self.par == "par1":
            do_something()
        elif self.par == "par2":
            do_something_else()

        do_more(self.par)
```

Comment: Could be. But that causes strange error `  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/unittest/case.py", line 320, in run
    self.setUp()
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable` AND that will require me to repeat @parametrized decorator for every single test method in the class. To avoid it I wanted to use it at the class level.